# Is there any proof that sieve of sundaram produces primes smaller than (2*x + 2) for a given number x?

Tags: algorithm

Here is the [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-sundaram-print-primes-smaller-n/) for Sieve of Sundaram to print all primes smaller than n . 
How can I prove that the entry in the *m*th column and nth row equals m+2*m*n+n as shown [here](http://banach.millersville.edu/~bob/math478/History/Sundaram.html)?
 Does i+j+2*i*j inculde all the numbers given in the array as shown [here](https://plus.maths.org/content/comment/6638#comment-6638) ?
How can I prove this too?
 
I know how this alogrithm works but I'm just curious to know the proof. I tried but could'nt prove the above things.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article [Sieve of Sundaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram) has two references that explain the algorithm well.  See;

- Ferrando, Elisabetta (2005).
- Baxter, Andrew.